# Dependency of $\mathrm{H_2O}$ surface tension on vapour pressure

Tags: thermodynamics, water, surface-tension

How is does the surface tension between:

- liquid water, and
- humid air

depend on

- $\mathrm{H_2O}$ partial pressure in the air, and
- temperature?

**Edit:** 
I assume that temperature and humidity will both lower the surface tension. But I'm searching for equations to quantify this effect.

I was trying to correlate, condensed particulate sizes in turbulent flow to changes in ambient parameters. The humidity and temperature might be important influence parameters, which influence surface tension and therefore droplet size in turbulent flow.

I can ensure, that this is not a homework question. I was searching information on this for my professional work. Unfortunatly googling did not give me the results I hoped for.

Comment: This is intereting Informationen Pieter. Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't seem homework for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Martin Chaplin's [water anomaly site](http://www1.lsbu.ac.uk/water/physical_anomalies.html#ST): "An interesting, if usually ignored, phenomenon is the linear reduction of surface tension with increasing relative humidity; ~0.1% drop per 1% increase in humidity at 5 °C."  With a reference to a paper from 2012.